# Can the L1 sunshade idea for climate control be adapted to work in LEO?

Tags: artificial-satellite, climate

There have been a few papers written on ways to put objects at the Earth-Sun L1 point to shade the Earth enough to counter-act global warming. There is a [Wikipedia page about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_sunshade), this paper called [Optimal Sunshade Configurations for Space-Based Geoengineering near the Sun-Earth L1 Point](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0136648), and this one called [Feasibility of cooling the Earth with a cloud of small spacecraft near the inner Lagrange point (L1)](http://www.pnas.org/content/103/46/17184.full).

I have seen almost nothing about whether a system in low Earth orbit might be able to compete with this, given the reduced delta V to put it up. Couldn't there be advantages to doing something nearby?

Comment: Oh, look - https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.05148. The size would seem to weigh against. I might be able to edit a bit to make this more specific, i'm not sure yet. Finding a way to make comparisons maybe is tough.

Comment: I looked at that ArXiv 2015 reprint of what is really a 2009 conference paper. They get a little crazy aggressively selecting some areas for shading more than others; that kind of sunlight redistribution could cause *a whole new kind* of climate change even harder to model or understand than the current problem.

Comment: @uhoh yes, i did get the impression that paper was a bit sloppy.

Comment: We can call it enthusiastic, optimistic, forward-thinking, or "out-of-the-box."

Comment: I'm not sure on the numbers so won't officially answer, but I think in LEO, you'd need to keep it moving to always between the Earth and Sun; something you get for free at L1. Also, moving it closer to the sun would create a larger shadow. These are just my guesses as to why L1 > LEO.

Comment: @coblr In LEO you'd have to set up a swarm of objects that form a belt around the Earth, so that as some leave the sunlit side in their orbit, others enter. While objects closer to the sun cast a larger umbra shadow, they cast a smaller penumbra shadow, so it isn't clear to me the total shadow would be less.